# how to set two instance variables to each other in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, methods, instance-variables

I'm working on Chris Pine's Ruby tutorial. I have to write a cheat method that allows me to set which side of the die I want to show: https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=09

I have two instance variables: @numberShowing and @numberCheat. @numberCheat receives an input from the user and I want to set @numberShowing to take the value of @numberCheat. However, @numberShowing always outputs some random number. Any tips?

Here's my code so far:

```
class Die
    def initialize
        roll
    end

    def roll
        @numberShowing = 1 + rand(6)
    end

    def showing
        @numberShowing
    end

    def cheat
        puts "cheat by selecting your die number between 1 and 6"
        @numberCheat = gets.chomp
    end
    @numberShowing = @numberCheat
end
puts Die.new.cheat
puts Die.new.showing
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should do the assignment to `@numberShowning` within some method, not within the class itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `@numberShowing = @numberCheat` into the `cheat` method. But your test is not going to prove it worked. Try something like:

```
die = Die.new
puts "Currently showing #{die.showing}"
puts "Cheating to change showing number to #{die.cheat}"
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! This worked. I even put another line afterwards: puts die.showing to test for it and the showing number took the value of the cheat number. Could you explain to me how that worked. Thanks